# flyway naming convention do not accept alpha numeric characters

Tags: sql, migration, naming, conventions, flyway

The attribute "version" in the schema_version table is VARCHAR2(50 BYTE).

when the DB migration script is named as `VB2042_1_First_Changes.sql` [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org) throws as error message.

Error: The version number should always start from 0..9

varchar2 data type should be able to accept alpha numeric data. Is this a bug in flyway 3.2 or is there any work around available out there.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like two problems to me with your naming.

- The **`V` must be followed by digits**.
  (You have a `B`.)
- A **double underscore** must separate the version number from the description.
  (Looks like you have only a single underscore.)

The key concept is that Flyway does translate your version number (the first part of your file name) to an actual Major.Minor.Micro.Nano style number like that commonly used in the software industry. In other words, your scripts’ version number is *not alphabetical*.

The `V` is required to identify this script as a one-time run, in contrast to a `R` which means repeatable, run every time. After that first character, after the `V`/`R`, comes your version number.

Each component of the version number is separated by either an underscore or a dot. Internally, the underscores are converted to dots, so I just use dots. Also, I like the dots as they contrast with the double underscore and any underscores I might have in the description portion, emphasizing that they make up an actual version number.

So your file named:

> VB2042_1_First_Changes.sql

…should have been named this way, dropping the `B` and adding a second underscore in middle…

> V2042_1__First_Changes.sql

…from which Flyway would internally produce a version number of `2042.1`.

Personally, I use an approximate date and hour-of-day as my scripts’ version number. And I use dots rather than underscores. So I would have used this for a script written in the evening of the 23rd of January this year.

> V2017.01.23_19__First_changes.sql

…from which Flyway would internally produce a version number of `2017.1.23.19`. Note how any leading zeros such as `01` here are ignored, as the string is converted into numbers.

Here is a slide from a talk I give on Flyway, summarizing these rules.

[image: a slide from a presentation on Flyway, summarizing naming rules.]

Comment: To be precise, a number does not come after an R -- they aren't versioned, after all